# динамическое обновление списка в python

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, pymysql

есть скрипт, который подключатся к БД (mysql) с помощью pymysql и использует данные из базы в своей работе (в виде списка)
как лучше будет организовать обновление данных в скрипте при обновлении базы данных (добавление/удаление записей) без перезапуска скрипта и без периодического опроса БД
сделать бэкэнд на каком-нибудь джанго или фласке или можно попроще?

Comment: Джанго и фласк сами по себе подразумевают постоянные перезапуски скрипта

Comment: Если у вас нет возможности вклиниться в процесс обновления базы данных, то с MySQL никак.

Comment: ну как нет возможности ?
отслеживать изменения не нужно
т.е при инициации обновления бд можно делать, например http-запрос, который будет делать рефреш

Comment: @sqlbastard1613 и в чём тогда вопрос? Делайте.

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял, скрипт создан для какой-то непрерывной работы и сам не принимает входящие запросы, лишь требует свежих данных. Можно поступить разными способами.

---

**Способ 1**

Просто периодически обращаться к БД и вытаскивать свежие данные. Можно это сделать в отдельном потоке, тогда стоит ещё подумать и о мьютексах. Можно в основном – поставить циклический счётчик и инкрементировать его при каждой итерации основной работы; или использовать вместо счётчика timestamp последнего обновления данных.

Такой подход прост и удобен, если данных не много, обновления происходят часто, а некоторые задержки несущественны.

---

**Способ 2**

Прикрутить Django/Flask чтобы принимать инфу об обновлении данных. Тогда уже основной код надо будет пускать в отдельном потоке и также использовать мьютексы.

Способ чуть посложнее, актуален, если данных много, обновления происходят редко, а задержки надо минимизировать.